# Statement of Markov-Kakutani fixed-point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Markov-Kakutani fixed-point theorem is usually stated as follows:

"Let $E$ be a locally convex topological vector space. Let $C$ be a compact convex subset of $E$. Let $S$ be a commuting family of self-mappings $T$ of $C$ which are continuous and affine, i.e. $T(tx +(1 – t)y) = tT(x) + (1 – t)T(y)$ for $t \in [0,1]$ and $x, y$ in $C$. Then the mappings have a common fixed point in $C$." (Wikipedia)

The proof that is given in wikipedia (following Reed-Simon) is based on the Hahn-Banach theorem which is where, I believe, the requirement of local convexity for $E$ is used. However, as far as I know there are other proofs of Markov-Kakutani theorem which avoid the Hahn-Banach theorem.

My question is whether the local convexity condition on $E$ is redundant in the statement of the theorem and it is included there only because of the preferred method of the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the local convexity condition is precisely because of the nice parallel with the Hahn-Banach theorem (in fact, Kakutani himself has a paper showing the Markov-Kakutani theorem implies the Hahn-Banach theorem as well).

The Markov-Kakutani theorem holds in any general Hausdorff topological vector space (see, for example, Dunford & Schwartz "Linear Operators. Part 1" p. 456).